# rest API return result from callback request of another endpoint

Tags: http, asynchronous

I want to standup an endpoint /foo which is a synchronous endpoint for clients but the response is dependent on a callback /foo_callback being called on the app as a result of the request to the synchronous endpoint.

to elaborate the workflow:

[Flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWFbW.png)

I havent decided on a technology to use so ideally would look for a recommendation.

High level what I am thinking of is starting an async thread in the request handler and check for an update on a singleton map to see if the server has responded but I am wondering if there is a better way

I dont have control over the client and cannot really use websocket or long polling.

Comment: What is the expected response time from your 'SomeApp' to that async method in your API? The reason this is relevant is because if you are planning to wait for any longer than a few seconds, you should consider changing this to an event based system rather than just a simple async await call. API with wait time of anything more than 10 seconds is not the best idea.

Comment: Also what are expected number of connections? In general your choice of technology should be based on loads of other factors such as platforms you want to reach over to, number of connections expected, latency you would like to stick to (or not cross over that threshold), type of users (mobile, desktop etc.), type of data being consumed etc.

Comment: less than 1 second. like I said in the post I do not control the client and cannot make it event based either. Well instead of knowing the expected number of connections, I want to choose a technology that gives me the highest throughput and obviously  I will measure that and then scale horizontally based on my expected number of connections.

Comment: your question is too open ended. Like I said in the comment above performance is one aspect. You have to think about other issues like skills, maintenance cost, maturity of technology, time and efforts required, costs, toolings, etc. There are too many competitors in the market. nodejs and asp.net are two main alternatives I can think of, though there are plenty others. Also check out gRPC - it is much faster but not REST style communication. In short, I think you have to put more boundaries around your specifications.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.